# OctoberCMS show value in list available instead of 1 and unavailable instead of 0

Tags: php, forms, list, octobercms

I have this in model:

```
 fields.yaml
    special_offer:
        label: special_offer
        type: Switch
        default: true
```

DB field is tinyint(1)

working good!

But I want to show in list not 0 or 1, but available/not available.
I can store string, but I prefer to convert it.

this accessor:

```
public function getSpecialOfferAttribute ($value){
        return ( $value === 1 ) ? 'available' : 'not available' ;
}
```

will show right in list, but wrong in form, since switch accepts only 0/1

How can  I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [custom column type](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#custom-column-types) for that. Define the custom column type in you `plugin.php` file:

```
public function registerListColumnTypes()
{
    return [
        // Convert special offer values to text
        'special_offer' => function($value) {
            $map = [
                0 => 'not available',       
                1 => 'available',       
            ];
            return $map[$value];
        }
    ];
}
```

And then in the list column definitions file use this:

```
special_offer:
    label: Special offer
    type: special_offer
```

Comment: So does it means that i cannot do it using existing types? I just wanted to use switch ((

Comment: If you want custom translations, then I think you dont have a choice. The switch uses translation strings `backend::lang.list.column_switch_true` and `backend::lang.list.column_switch_false`

Comment: sad! wrote in october forum, hope will get answer from the there )
thanks

Comment: But, you can still use the switch on your fields.yaml and only update the columns.yaml that's the purpose of that file